# Share screen session with users in the same group (Linux)

Tags: linux, permissions, gnu-screen, groups

I can create a detached screen session using the following command:

```
[user1@host-pc ~]$ screen -d -m -S sname program
```

...and resume to it using this command:

```
[user1@host-pc ~]$ screen -r sname
```

**Is there a way to let users that are in the same group as `user1` access the session?**

*Edit: I've read the man page, and I know about the multiuser mode. I'm asking specifically about allowing to share screen sessions by user groups (/etc/group).*

*i.e. all users in group `users` are allowed to share session `sname`. Without manually acladd'ing each user to screen.*

Comment: The answer appears to be "no, you cannot (without scripting or source code modifications)." Screen (at least recent versions) has many built-in checks to prevent tampering with permissions on the sockets in `/var/run/screen` outside of its `acladd` and `aclgrp` facility, and you will get messages like `Directory /var/run/screen/S-username must have mode 700` if you have altered those permissions manually.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible, but your screen should have suid bit on and this has some security implications. Basically you should do the following in order to be able to share a screen session:

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/screen
```

Then as a user (let's suppose that its username is *user1*), you should run screen and run the following two commands in it:

```
<ctrl+a>:multiuser on
<ctrl+a>:acladd user2
```

Finally, *user2* should be able to connect to the session with the following command:

```
screen -x user1/
```

You can find more information [here](http://tipotheday.com/2008/01/23/screen-sharing-cli-style/).

Comment: This is a very good summary of multi-user mode (and thanks!), but unfortunately does not answer the OP question of how to directly add an **entire `/etc/group` group** for access to the multi-user session.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable multiuser mode either via .screenrc, or within the session by using Ctrl+a : with `multiuser on`. Access can then be controlled by adding individual users with `acladd user2`, or by re-creating group lists within screen acls (`aclgrp`).

I do not believe there is a way to directly use unix groups for screen multiuser ACLs.

See `man screen` or http://aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser

Comment: Here is a [Wayback Machine capture](https://web.archive.org/web/20160729064820/http://aperiodic.net:80/screen/multiuser) of that page on aperiodic.net before bit rot set in.

Answer (score 0):

Hello from the year 2020! The answer still seems to be "no, you cannot (without scripting or source code modifications)."

I have a suspicion (but only), that this may be one of those circumstances where [Expect](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Expect)—a [surprisingly underappreciated Unix automation tool](https://blog.robertelder.org/don-libes-expect-unix-automation-tool/)—may come in handy.

Screen, at least recent versions, has many built-in checks to prevent tampering with permissions on the sockets in `/var/run/screen` outside of its `acladd` and `aclgrp` facility.

If you try to make the permissions on `/var/run/screen/S-username` more permissive (to give another Unix group access), you will still get an error message like

```
Must run suid root for multiuser support.
```

if you attempt to `screen -r username/` with an existing socket.

If you `sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/screen`, you will get the error message

```
Directory /var/run/screen/S-username must have mode 700
```

if you have altered those permissions manually, which would seem to preclude using `chmod` or `setfacl` to set permissions on the socket at the filesystem level. If you've met Screen's expectations as far as filesystem permissions, but haven't explicitly added the user trying to access the socket to the access list with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> `:acladd`, you get the error message

```
Access to session denied.
```

Offhand, I don't know of any easy solutions to your problem offered by [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) either, but [wemux](https://github.com/zolrath/wemux) seems to be a popular wrapper for making multi-user shared sessions easier to work with, and might help you in achieving your goals.

**Edit**: This tidbit from aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser ([Wayback capture](https://web.archive.org/web/20160729064820/http://aperiodic.net:80/screen/multiuser)) makes it seem like you could script the `:acladd` operations while iterating over the membership of a particular group from `/etc/group` by first transmitting the following escape sequence:

> screen can allow programs to send commands to it via the escape sequence `ESC ] 83 ; cmd ^G;` in order for this to work, the pseudo-user `:window:` must exist and have the appropriate permissions to execute the supplied command.